# When changing a subscription, how to know if CC is in stripe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

Say a customer already exists within stripe, but the credit card (source) may or not be present in the system.

If a customer is changing a subscription, how do I know wether I need to display the credit card form or not?  i.e. if the credit card is already setup in stripe, I should be able to change subscriptions without asking them again.

Comment: Are you asking how to [get a list of cards](https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#list_cards) for a particular customer?

Comment: @coreyward no i'm not, but that may be the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the customer object in Stripe before loading the form and check the source property which contains a list of the existing payment methods linked to this customer:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#customer_object-sources

You might also want to have a place to allow your customer to handle and change his credit cards in his account in a separate place. There is this recipe explaining how to do it:

https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/updating-customer-cards

This is done in PHP but you should be able to easily adapt it to ruby as the logic stays the same.